# Efficiently find all .zip files on an S3 bucket

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I've got a bunch of S3 buckets littered with old files and archives (in .zip format). I want to effectively query a bucket and get a list of all files that are zipped and are larger than, say, 200MB and then remove them.

So I wrote some code. It does the job, but it's slow. The more files on an S3, the more API calls, the longer the wait. For a bucket with 70+ files, it takes approximately 50 seconds, to nail down, in this case, 3 zip files.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.6
import boto3
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError


def find_all_zips(bucket: str) -> iter:
    print(f"Looking for .zip files on S3: {bucket} ...")
    b = boto3.resource("s3").Bucket(bucket)
    return (obj.key for obj in b.objects.all()
            if get_info(bucket=bucket, key=obj.key) is not None)


def get_info(bucket: str, key: str) -> str:
    s3 = boto3.client('s3')
    try:
        response = s3.head_object(Bucket=bucket, Key=key)
        has_size = response['ContentLength'] >= 209715200 # ~= 200MB in bytes
        if len(response['ContentType']) == 0:
            is_zip = False
        else:
            is_zip = response['ContentType'].split("/")[1] == 'zip'

        if has_size and is_zip:
            return key
    except ClientError as error:
        raise Exception(f"Failed to fetch file info for {key}: {error}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(list(find_all_zips(bucket='MYBUCKET')))
```

The output I get is what I expect:

```
Looking for .zip files on S3: MYBUCKET ...
['avocado-prices.zip', 'notepad.zip', 'spacerace.zip']
```

**Question:** Is there a way to speed this thing up? Or should I spin up a database that keeps tabs on my S3 files and their types?

Comment: The code runs from lambda function ?

Comment: No, I run it on my local machine.

Comment: Consider enabling and querying an S3 inventory report.

Comment: Link: [Amazon S3 Inventory - Amazon Simple Storage Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/storage-inventory.html)

Comment: The slowless is due to networking and probably your internet connection.   2 things you can do.  First, try running your code from an EC2 or Lambda.   Second,  check for zip file using the key before calling the head_object to check for size.  This will reduce the number of API calls you need to make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are willing to use the filename to identify a Zip file, then you do not need the additional call to `head_object()`:

```py
import boto3

s3_resource = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3_resource.Bucket('my_bucket')

max_size = 2 * 1024 * 1024

print(list(object.key for object in bucket.objects.all()
            if object.size >= max_size and object.key.endswith('.zip')))
```